# BeautifulSoup: Combining continious NavigableString into single NavigableString

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>A <span>die</span> is thrown \(x = {-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 fromboth the throws?</p>
<p> Test </p>
</body>
<html>
```

I am trying to wrap `\(x = {-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)` within span tags. I was able to do so when  `is thrown \(x = {-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from both the throws?` is a single NavigableString but in some cases  `is thrown \(x = {-b \pm\`, `sqrt{b^2-4ac}` and `\over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from both the throws?` are split up into three NavigableString. So is there any way using beautifulsoup to merge continuous NavigableString to a single NavigableString.

The code which I used to wrap them within span tag when (x = {-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a})` is withn a single NavigableString.

```
mathml_regex = re.compile(r'\\\(.*?\\\)', re.DOTALL)
def mathml_wrap(soup):
    for p_tags in soup.find_all('p'):
        for p_child in p_tags.children:
            try:
                match = re.search(mathml_regex, p_child)
                if match:
                    start = match.start()
                    end = match.end()
                    text = p_child
                    new_str = NavigableString(text[:start])
                    p_child.replace_with(new_str)
                    new_str1 = NavigableString(text[end:])
                    span_tag = soup.new_tag("span", **{'class':'math-tex'})
                    span_tag.string= text[start:end]
                    new_str.insert_after(span_tag)
                    span_tag.insert_after(new_str1)
            except TypeError:
                pass
```

Edit:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """<p>
     A 
     <span>die</span> 
      is thrown \(x = {-b \pm 
      <span>\sqrt</span>
      {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from
    both the throws?
    </p> <p> Test </p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
mathml_start_regex = re.compile(r'\\\(')
mathml_end_regex = re.compile(r'\\\)')

for p_tags in soup.find_all('p'):
    match = 0 #Flag set to 1 if '\(' is found and again set back to 0 if '\)' is found.
    for p_child in p_tags.children:
        try: #Captures Tags that contains \(
            if re.findall(mathml_start_regex, p_child.text):
                match += 1
        except: #Captures NavigableString that contains \(
            if re.findall(mathml_start_regex, p_child):
                match += 1
        try: #Replaces Tag with Tag's text
            if match == 1:
                p_child.replace_with(p_child.text)
        except: #No point in replacing NavigableString since they are just strings without Tags
            pass
        try: #Captures Tags that contains \)
            if re.findall(mathml_end_regex, p_child.text):
                match = 0
        except: #Captures NavigableString that contains \)
            if re.findall(mathml_end_regex, p_child):
                match = 0
```

After processing my soup with the above code to remove the span tag between `\(` and `\)`
`is thrown \(x = {-b \pm\`, `sqrt` and `{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from both the throws?` are split up into 3 NavigableStrings in my soup object.

Comment: Can you give an example of how your html will look it these navigable strings are split up?
Also, you want to parse those split up strings in one string?

Comment: @Darpan I have edited the question. Yes I do want to parse those as one string so that I can wrap them within span tags

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question properly, but as you said you want to concatenate the string you are getting in those `<p>` tags,

I used this as input -

```
mystr = """<html>
<body>
<p>A <span>die</span> is thrown \(x = {-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 fromboth the throws?</p>
<p> Test </p>
</body>
<html>"""
```

So here is what I did -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr,"lxml")
my_p =  soup.findAll("p")
for p in my_p:
    print p.text
```

This extracts whole text you are getting in the `<p>` tag, tell me if your question was something else.

Comment: in my code `is thrown \(x = {-b \pm\`, `sqrt` and `{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from both the throws?` are three continuous NavigableString. I want to merge them into single Navigablestring so that  `match = re.search(mathml_regex, p_child)` from my code can match the pattern

Comment: I am not able to understand it clearly what you are trying to say here.. can you mark each of three navigable strings as 1,2,3? And give the exact html that you have as input, and give exact output that you wish to extract.